# how can Azure Web App receive email SMTP?

Tags: asp.net, azure, smtp, azure-web-app-service

My .NET web app presently uses Azure Windows server VM to receive and send SNMP email.  My users send email to my web app, and my Windows server VM receives this email into its SNMP and then deposits it into a folder, which gets read by my backend .NET app.

I'm interested in switching to the new Azure web app model, but can't find anywhere how it would receive email.

My DNS provider uses my MX RECORD configuration to forward email from my users to the IP of my present VM server and then to its SNMP receive service, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To receive email with a Web App in Azure App Service, you can setup a Web Job that can poll for new emails on a Schedule or Manual trigger, then perform a custom action necessary.

Another alternative is that you could create an Azure Logic App that is wired up to be notified of email messages. This can be done using the Outlook connectors (if you're using an Outlook email) or other connectors. Then the Logic App can be setup to make an API call to your app to trigger some sort of custom action to take place for emails received.

The configuration you have today on a full VM can not be implemented in Azure App Service Web Apps. The underlying managed VM that hosts the Web App isn't accessible and configurable in this way.